# Calculating turn-on time of MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I have a [BSZ018N04LS6](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-BSZ018N04LS6-DataSheet-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d46269e1c0190169e2e8e05601f7) MOSFET that is used to drive a relay. I'm trying to determine the turn on/off time.

The relay is connected to a 12 V battery. The MOSFET is driven by a 20 V driver. When it's turned on it will see 20 V, but when it's disconnected it will see 0 V (sorry for the image, it makes it look like it will be floating). The gate resistor is 10 Ω.

How do I determine the turn-on time?

Can I say 20 V/10 Ω = 2 A, and then take the total gate charge (15 nC), and divide by 2 A? This gives 7.5 ns for the turn-on time.

When I try modeling it by Ciss (2 nF), I get a time constant of 20 ns, and 3 times that would be 60 ns, so 60 ns to turn on.

Which one is correct? Or, if both are incorrect, how do I model it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome! EE top tip: s = seconds, S = siemens.

Comment: Next top-tip: the relay will probably take one million times longer to turn on than the MOSFET

Comment: The diode lack a "line" ...

Comment: NB: The 20 V applied on the grid are perhaps a "little" too "big". Check the datasheet. Just at the limit ! 5V or 10 V would be enough.

Comment: @Antonio51: yes, 20V is probably too much: most power MOSFETs have 20V as an absolute maximum.  But also, most MOSFETs are specified with 12V on the gate -- a MOSFET that'll turn on with 5V on the gate is logic level, which is a mild specialty item.  As always, read the datasheet for your particular part.

Comment: Note that as shown you should be worried about the turn **off** behavior of the FET -- if that's really how you're doing it, then when the switch opens there's nothing to make the FET turn off at all -- the gate voltage could just meander down by leakage, leaving the FET at 6V with lots of current going through it.  Unless it's way oversized for correct operation, it'd send up a smoke signal to let you know you screwed up.

Comment: NB: a relay has also a serial resistor ... some few dozen of Ohm.

Comment: sorry, you are correct it's not being driven by 20V. The pre-driver is at 10V. I still haven't seen an answer of how to calculate the turn on and turn off times. I could hook it up to a scope, but it would be nice to know how to get the results on paper first.

Answer (score 1):

The turn-on time is not important, because the electrical time constant of the relay is orders of magnitude longer than the turn-on time of the mosfet and the mechanical time constant is usually longer still. What you should be calculating is the relay’s time constants. The mosfet is completely transparent here - it acts like an ideal switch.

There’s zero current at turn-on thus no turn-on conduction loss, since an inductor current always starts at zero when you apply voltage. Only parasitic capacitances will conduct on turn-on and those are very small.

Turn-off is determined by gate leakage and will take longer the colder it is. In dry ice, with no moisture, it might take hours for the mosfet to turn off.

An SPST switch cannot be the sole means of controlling the gate. You probably meant a square wave source, right?

Comment: Yes it's really a square wave.

Answer (score 0):

I will make the assumption that your 20V voltage source is representing a MOSFET driver.
If this is the case the turn-on time depends on the driver performance (source current) and Ciss/Crss of the MOSFET.

Basically MOSFET switching time can be decomposed in two steps:

- Driver sourcing current to charge Cgs from 0 to Vgs_th
- Driver sourcing current to charge Cgd (also named Crss). This really corresponds to the switching time. This phenomenon is called "Miller plateau"

Then the driver sources current to charge Cgs fully to Vdriver. But this time is not part of switching time.

Please see following application note for equations:  https://www.vishay.com/docs/73217/an608a.pdf

Also you can use LTSpice which will give you more accurate results

Comment: see figure 2 of this document